# window.location.replace not working Laravel ajax

Tags: php, laravel

i am a beginner of laravel. i made the custom login form using laravel Ajax.when enter the username and password and click sign in button it is successfully visit to test.blade.php page but page displayed 404
Not Found what tried so far i attached below.

**test.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <table class="table-bordered" width="350" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <form name="frm_login" id="frm_login">
                    @csrf
                          <tr>
                              <td height="25" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FF9900" class="style2">
                                  <div align="center">
                                      <strong>Login</strong>
                                  </div>

                              </td>
                          </tr>

                        <tr>

                            <div id="err" style="color: red">


                            </div>

                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td width="118" align="left" valign="middle" class="style1">Username</td>
                            <td width="118" align="left" valign="middle" class="style1">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="10px" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="118" align="left" valign="middle" class="style1">Password</td>
                            <td width="118" align="left" valign="middle" class="style1">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" size="10px" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                       

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle" class="style1">

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login()">Sign In</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
                                </td>


                        </tr>






                    </form>
                </table>

            </td>


        </tr>


    </table>





</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>




<script>

    function login()
    {
        if($('#username').val() == "")
        {
            $('#username').parent('td').addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#password').val() == "")
        {
            $('#password').parent('td').addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#utype').val() == "")
        {
            $('#utype').parent('td').addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }
        var data = $("#frm_login").serialize();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });




        $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('testlogin.check') }}',
                data : data,

            success : function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
                if(response == 1)
                {
                    window.location.replace('test.blade.php');
                }
                else if(response == 3)
                {
                    $("#err").hide().html("Username or Password or Role Incorrect. Please Check").fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }

        });
    }

</script>
```

**testContoller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestloginController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('testlogin');
    }

    public function check(Request $request)
{  
    $user = $request->username;
    $pass  = $request->password;

    if (auth()->attempt(array('name' => $user, 'password' => $pass)))
    {
        return response()->json([ [1] ]);
    } 
    else
     {  
        return response()->json([ [3] ]);
     }  
}

    public function logout(Request $request) 
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        return redirect()->route('student.login');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/test','TestloginController@index');
Route::post('/test/check','TestloginController@check')->name('testlogin.check');
```

Route::get('/test','TestloginController@index')->name('testlogin.login');

Comment: yes. i am new to ajax with laravel

Comment: is the ajax request is correct

Comment: you need to compare in your success callback response == "success"

Comment: ya i copied this code from my core php. i don't how to compare in larvel controller please help

Comment: return response()->json('1');   like how to write and check

Comment: if you use single quotes it consider as a string  pass without single quote or you make a array and pass

Comment: pass this way  return response()->json([ [1] ]);

Comment: now working but if the username and pasword match it goes to test.blade.php page not show any thing 404
Not Found

Comment: i called like this way window.location.replace('test.blade.php');

Comment: @haridran , you need to define routes window.location.replace('dashboard');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code. you must change only an action(function) in your controller you called "check".
please change to the:

```
public function check(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if (\Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([[1]]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([[3]]);
        }
    }
```

after that you must watch

```
            window.location.replace('test.blade.php');
```

change to

```
window.location.replace('{{route("your destination route name"}}');
```

Comment: this working my problem inside ajax function the json value coming 1 it will redirected test.blade.php   but page displayed 404 Not Found

Comment: window.location.replace('test.blade.php'); here how to call to test.blade page with session

Comment: window.location.replace('{{route("test.index"}}');   i wrote the like getting error syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' (View:

Comment: you must redirect to the Url or route such as my example
java script can't access to view file...